# How to define the next object in the street with android?

Tags: android, algorithm, google-maps, gps, gis

I wanna put objects in a map and discover which is the closest objet from me, supposing that I'm in a moving car with my cell phone. Thus, to define the closest object I need to take the orientation of the movement and the street into account. The following figure illustrate the situation:

[image]

So, object 2 is the closest object, but it is not in the same street as I'm (the car). The object 1 is the closest object in the street that I'm , but I'm going to the opposite side. Finnaly, the object 3 is the one I want, since it is the closest object in the same street I'm and also following the orientation of my movement.

**Does anybody know how I can obtain the closest object to me (considering that I'm moving) according to the rule I just mentioned?**

I actually don't need to visually show the map, but I need to put the objets in some abstract representation of a map (with the real streets of any city), get my current location and movement orientation in order to define which one is the next object.

PS: If you don't know an API, but know what kind of concepts and stuff I need to study would be helpful, because I'm new in android and geographic systems development.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know of an API, but the math should be fairly simple. If you have an associative array holding the (lat,long) as the key, and the objects as the values, you should be able to do a fast lookup of the surrounding objects, then just find the closest one to a set coord (your location?).

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not that simple, as I mentioned in the question. For example, object 1 is the closest object, but it is not in the same street as I'm (the car). The object 2 is the closest object in the street that I'm , but I'm going to the opposite side. Finnaly, the object 3 is the one I want, since it is the closest object in the same street I'm and also following the orientation of my movement.

To make the things even more complicated, you can imagine more exotic streets with curve trajectories.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that. And unless I'm misunderstanding, 1 is on the same road as you ("Rui Barbosa"), while 2 is on a different street ("... Amizade").

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The phrase should be: object 2 is the closest object, but it is not in the same street as I'm (the car). The object 1 is the closest object in the street that I'm , but I'm going to the opposite side. Finnaly, the object 3 is the one I want, since it is the closest object in the same street I'm and also following the orientation of my movement.

Comment: Even if you know the objects bearing then still object 1 will be the closest! But to cater you can put a check if the car distance is increasing from some object with same bearing then ignore otherwise you have found the closet!